# Java scanner returning filename instead of file content

Tags: java

I am trying to read the contents of a file:

```
Scanner fileReader = new Scanner("myFile.txt");
int counter = 0;
while(fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
    
    if(counter == 0) {
        System.out.println("IT IS READING " + fileReader.nextLine());
    }
}
```

**myFile.txt** content:

HELLO WORLD

HELLO WORLD

Instead of printing hello world:

I am getting:
IT IS READING myFile.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are initializing a scanner with java.util.Scanner(String) constructor, and this constructor simply creates a Scanner which reads out the String you passed in.

What you actually need is in order to read out a file is:

```
Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File("myFile.txt"));
int counter = 0;
while(fileReader.hasNextLine()) {

    if(counter == 0) {
        System.out.println("IT IS READING " + fileReader.nextLine());
    }
}
```